# Set session string from input value onfocusout

Tags: javascript, c#, session, asp.net-core

I am trying to set a session variable on the `onfocusout` event of an input, to what was just entered into that input.

I have tried straight javascript ie.

`var e = document.getElementById("Supervisor");`
`sessionStorage.setItem('_Supervisor', e);`

Although the value is not kept after postback.

```
<input value="@HttpContext.Session.GetString("_Supervisor")" id="Supervisor"
    class="form-control" onfocusout="UpdateSuper()" />

<script language="javascript">
    function UpdateSuper()
    {
        @{HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Supervisor", getElementById('Supervisor').value);};
    }
</script>
```

I may be confused by trying to combine two different methods, but am looking for a fast and efficient way of setting this value without postback.

Comment: Is that web matrix? I'm not too familiar, but have you looked into `Page Methods`? (Part of ASP.NET AJAX. Out of fashion but works for using code behind from javascript.)

Comment: JavaScript sessionStorage is client side, HttpContext.Session is server side. They don't touch

Comment: You can’t run server-side code like that within some JavaScript event handler. You generally cannot interact with the server side unless you actively send a new request to the server (e.g using AJAX). – The server will just render the HTML and then you have a fixed source being sent to the client which is executed there. Just look at the source code within your browser to see what ends up there (`CTRL+U`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the session? ~ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#session-state

Would you consider something that does not require configurations and is more flexible like **TempData** ~ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tempdata

or

**ViewBag** or **ViewData** ~ https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-viewbag-viewdata/